# NoMethodError - undefined method `safe_constantize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am trying to create an ActionCable chatroom following the actioncable guide on GoRails.com.

As I am trying to connect to ActionCable I get following error:
NoMethodError - undefined method `safe_constantize' for nil:NilClass

```
[ActionCable] [User 1] Could not execute command from 
{"command"=>"subscribe", "identifier"=>"
{\"ChatroomsChannel\":\"ChatroomsChannel\",\"room_id\":1}"}) 
[NoMethodError - undefined method `safe_constantize' for 
nil:NilClass]: /Users/Mathias/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.2.3@chatroomv1/gems/actioncable-
5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:29:in `add' | 
/Users/Mathias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@chatroomv1/gems/actioncable-
5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:15:in 
`execute_command' | /Users/Mathias/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.2.3@chatroomv1/gems/actioncable-
5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:88:in 
`dispatch_websocket_message' | /Users/Mathias/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.2.3@chatroomv1/gems/actioncable-
5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:54:in `block in invoke' | 
/Users/Mathias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@chatroomv1/gems/actioncable-
5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:39:in `block in work'
```

My app/channels/chatrooms_channel.rb looks like this:

```
def subscribed
   @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:room_id])
   #puts params[:room_id]
   #current_user.join_room(@chatroom)
   stream_from "chatrooms:#{@chatroom.id}"
   # stream_from "some_channel"
end
```

Maybe it is worth mentioning that I upgraded to rails 5.0.0.rc2 from rails 4.

Thank you,

Comment: Not familiar with action_cable, but it seems that it expects `channel` as the key for channel name, not `ChatroomsChannel` as you have.

Answer (score 1):

in `assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.coffee`

If you need to assign `params`, channel name must be in params hash too:

```
App['chatroom' + roomId] = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
  channel: 'ChatroomChannel',
  room_id: roomId
}, {
  received: ->
    ...
}
```

And only if you don't need `params`, you can write channel name without hash:

```
App.chatroom = App.cable.subscriptions.create 'ChatroomChannel',
  received: ->
    ...
```